# pgfplots: Use \times symbol for scientific notation in plot axes

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

When creating a plot like this one

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        scaled y ticks=false,
        yticklabel style={
            /pgf/number format/.cd,
            sci,
            sci generic={mantissa sep=\times,exponent={10^{#1}}}
            }
        ]
        \addplot coordinates {
            (1, 972817.3879)
            (2, 1436186.725)
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I'm trying to use scientific notation in the  y axis with `\times` as the mantissa separator instead of the default `\cdot`. The exponent is not showing up, though. I looked at Section 4.12.1 in the `pgfplots` manual and Section 2.7 in the `pgfplotstable` manual and followed the examples there, but there were no examples using this particular case with `yticklabel`.

How do I fix this?

The plot may be viewed here:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,
sci,
sci generic={mantissa sep=\times,exponent={10^{#1}}}}
    \begin{axis}[
        scaled y ticks=false,
        xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed},
        ]
        \addplot coordinates {
            (1, 972817.3879)
            (2, 1436186.725)
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've found that I can also move the `\pgfkeys` command inside of the `tikzpicture` environment so that it is only in effect inside of that scope.

Comment: @NickMoe yes; it's better to move it keep the change local; I'll edit my answer to reflect this.

Comment: One minor niggle I have with this solution is that 0 is displayed as `0 x 10^0` which most journals would frown upon. Is there a way to override the display and simply display it as 0? (Yes, it's silly to have a linear plot ranging from 0 to `10^6` but I'd be curious to know!)

Answer (score 5):

## `####`?

We need more `#`!  Four to be exact: `####1`.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        scaled y ticks=false,
        yticklabel style={
            /pgf/number format/.cd,
            sci,
            sci generic={mantissa sep=\times,exponent=10^{####1}}
            }
        ]
        \addplot coordinates {
            (1, 972817.3879)
            (2, 1436186.725)
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Using directly `\pgfmathprintnumber`

You can use the style `yticklabel` and its internal `\tick` macro directly with `\pgfmathprintnumber`. The superscript is—as you already know—the first parameter, but as nesting goes we need the second level, therefore: `##1`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      scaled y ticks=false,
      yticklabel={
        \pgfmathprintnumber[
          sci,
          sci generic={
            mantissa sep=\times,
            exponent={10^{##1}}
          }
        ]{\tick}
      }
    ]
        \addplot coordinates {
            (1, 972817.3879)
            (2, 1436186.725)
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: Output]

Answer (score 3):

You can see the explanation for the `tick scale binop` option in `page 233` of the `pgplots` manual.

Try the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        scaled y ticks=false,
        yticklabel style={
            /pgf/number format/.cd,
            sci,
            sci generic={mantissa sep=\times,exponent={10^{#1}}} 
            },
        tick scale binop={\textbackslash times} % Change \cdot to \times as mantissa separator
        ]
        \addplot coordinates {
            (1, 972817.3879)
            (2, 1436186.725)
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

### Edit

Gonzalo Medina already has posted a workaround regarding the missing exponents. Just in case *it is* an option not to write the mantissa the way you did, you can have the following option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[tick scale binop=\times,
        ]
        \addplot coordinates {
            (1, 972817.3879)
            (2, 1436186.725)
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]