# pgfplots axis multiplier \times symbol

Tags: pgfplots

Similar to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81862/pgfplots-use-times-symbol-for-scientific-notation-in-plot-axes), I want the scientific `\times` symbol instead of the * symbol for pgfplots' multipliers.
However, I need it for the whole axis-multiplier and not for every tick like in the other question.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis} [xmin=0, xmax=10000, ymin=0, ymax=10000]
        \addplot plot coordinates {(5000, 5000)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Illustration]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pgfplots has a `tick scale binop` option for this:

[image]

It is located under the `/pgfplots` path, hence:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[/pgfplots/tick scale binop=\times]
    \begin{axis} [xmin=0, xmax=10000, ymin=0, ymax=10000]
        \addplot plot coordinates {(5000, 5000)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You can also use:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis} [tick scale binop=\times,xmin=0, xmax=10000, ymin=0, ymax=10000]
```

or alternatively:

```
\pgfplotsset{tick scale binop=\times}
```

in the preamble. The result:

[image]

Comment: Perfect - I placed `\pgfplotsset {/pgfplots/tick scale binop=\times}` in my preamble to set it for every plot

Comment: @Mash: you're welcome. Your solution is excellent; one minor point though: `\pgfplotsset` already sets the main path `/pgfplots`, hence `\pgfplotsset{tick scale binop=\times}` will also work.