# Change mantissa sep on axis exponent

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have the following latex code generating a plot.
I want to change the scientific notation mantissa sep to a `\times` not `cdot`, this is for the y axis (x10-4). I don't want all the other numbers to be in scientific notation too.
[image: Incorrect Scientific notation plot]
I have tried `\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/sci generic/mantissa sep=\times}`
but that has not worked. What do I need to change

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.00000,0.44700,0.74100}%
\definecolor{mycolor2}{rgb}{0.85000,0.32500,0.09800}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/sci generic/mantissa sep=\times}

\begin{axis}[%
width=(\hsize/2),
height=(\hsize/2),
scale only axis,
xmin=0,
xmax=0.5,
xlabel near ticks,
xlabel={Density $\lambda$},
ymin=0,
ymax=0.00035,
ylabel near ticks,
ylabel={Rate, ($s^{-1}$)},
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left,
xmajorgrids,
ymajorgrids,
legend style={legend cell align=left, align=left}
]
\addplot [color=mycolor1, mark=o, mark options={solid, mycolor1}]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1e-05   0.000349984346613178\\
0.0250095   0.000294763280950208\\
0.100008    0.000223262905327838\\
0.1750065   0.000189761632377871\\
0.250005    0.000168814588345592\\
0.3250035   0.000153988764794569\\
0.400002    0.000142726344312675\\
0.4750005   0.000133766561301556\\
0.5 0.000131160050335831\\
};\label{rate_plot}
\addlegendentry{Rate}

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{document}
```

Similar to [pgfplots: Use \times symbol for scientific notation in plot axes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81862/pgfplots-use-times-symbol-for-scientific-notation-in-plot-axes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key that changes the `.10` to `x10` is `tick scale binop=\times` as in 4.15.3 Tick Scaling - Common Factors In Ticks in the PGFPlots documentation.

Corrected code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.00000,0.44700,0.74100}%
\definecolor{mycolor2}{rgb}{0.85000,0.32500,0.09800}%
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=(\hsize/2),
height=(\hsize/2),
scale only axis,
xmin=0,
xmax=0.5,
xlabel near ticks,
xlabel={Density $\lambda$},
ymin=0,
ymax=0.00035,
ylabel near ticks,
ylabel={Rate, ($s^{-1}$)},
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left,
xmajorgrids,
ymajorgrids,
legend style={legend cell align=left, align=left},
tick scale binop=\times
]
\addplot [color=mycolor1, mark=o, mark options={solid, mycolor1}]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1e-05   0.000349984346613178\\
0.0250095   0.000294763280950208\\
0.100008    0.000223262905327838\\
0.1750065   0.000189761632377871\\
0.250005    0.000168814588345592\\
0.3250035   0.000153988764794569\\
0.400002    0.000142726344312675\\
0.4750005   0.000133766561301556\\
0.5 0.000131160050335831\\
};\label{rate_plot}
\addlegendentry{Rate}

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{document}
```